# how to get the url inserted into a Ext.form.TextField in a variable value in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

how to get the url inserted into a Ext.form.TextField in  a variable value??.

if I create a variable x in Javascript, but I need to add a url as the value that a user in a Ext.form.TextField, but the variable and Ext.form.TextField are in different script on the same page.

thanks for your help and attention

Comment: Please rewrite question, I didn't understand anything at all

Comment: Hello, modify the question I understand that my problem is something particular, I will consider all responses thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand your question but if you say how to get the field value and set the return value to a variable, try to find the field with Ext then call the .getValue() and set the return value to your variable